# calling Base class constructor vs initializing member variables in Child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

The `Parent` class is an abstract class. Here `_isDone`, `_prob` are `protected` variables of `Parent` class, that are inherited by `Child`.

What is the difference between using:

`Child::Child(int _classType) : Parent(false, 1.0f)` for initializing the variables of the `Parent` class.

vs.

```
Child::Child(int _classType) 
{
    _isDone = false;
    _prob = 1.0f;
}
```

I feel it is easier to use the second rather than the first. Any reason to use the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: The first one is **initialization**, while the second one is **assignment**.

The first one initializes `_isDone` and `_prob` with `Parent`'s constructor. However, when you are using the second one, `_isDone` and `_prob` are initialized with `Parent`'s default constructor, and then they are assigned new values in `Child` constructor's function body.

**The first one is better** for the following reasons:

1. If `Parent` doesn't have default constructor, the second one CANNOT work.
2. The first one is more efficient, especially when the data member is a 'very large' object, whose default constructor is very expensive. Since the first one calls default constructor for the data member, and then calls `operator=` to assign a new value, while the second one just calls a proper constructor. The default constructor is redundant.
3. Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to access the `Parent`'s data member directly: coupling increases between `Parent` and `Child`.